# Error code 80131501 in COM+ registration of a .NET component

Tags: .net, com+

I'm trying to install my .NET COM+ component into a 64-bit Windows 2012 environment, but keep hitting the following error. Details from the event log are:

> Installation of `D:\xxx.dll` into `{71DE092C-FFED-4C75-901E-70DFFBE27EBF}` failed with an exception:
>
> ```
> System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationException: Could not install type library 'D:\xxx.tlb' into application 'Batch Process'.
> at System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationDriver.InstallAssembly(RegistrationConfig regConfig, Object obSync)
> at System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper.InstallAssemblyFromConfig(RegistrationConfig& regConfig)
> at System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper.InstallAssembly(String assembly, String& application, String partition, String& tlb, InstallationFlags installFlags)
> at System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.ComManagedImportUtil.InstallAssembly(String asmpath, String parname, String appname)
> ```

I tried disabling the Windows 2012 UAC as suggested by some and also copied the `.snk` file into same folder as the DLL. But all didn't work. I'm able to register this DLL into the GAC, which suggests it's already strongly named.